# Binding an image link, taken from DB and showing the picture in GridView (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

My project is a library and it uses a service to get a list of books. Each book has an Image URL, and i would like to show it like I show the other properties (which work)
Here is a part of my code (publisher etc. show properly)

```
  <GridViewColumn Header="Publisher" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Publisher.Pubname}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="shelf"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Shelf}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="genre"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Genre.GenreName}" />
                <GridViewColumn   >
                        <Image Source="{Binding Img}"/>
                </GridViewColumn>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
 public partial class BList : Window
{
    Service1Client client;
    public BList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RefreshData();

    }

    private void RefreshData()
    {
         client = new Service1Client();
        List<Book> bl = client.SelectAllBooks();
        Books.ItemsSource = bl;
    }
```

Books is the name of the ListView

Comment: I found that the best way to go here is to use a converter and then make it return a `BitmapSource` otherwise WPF will not display it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prepare DataTemplate for a cell:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="SomeHeader">
  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Image Source="{Binding Img}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```